# variational formulation of linear elasticity

Tags: pde, well-posedness, elliptic-pde

First I'm not 100% sure I'm on the good stack for asking my question. I would like to get a bilinear form for linear elasticity that separate a rotational part from a pure divergence part, so starting from the Navier equation 
\begin{equation} \mu \nabla^2 \mathbf u +(\mu+\lambda)\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf u) + \mathbf f =0 \end{equation}

Then I use the vector Laplacian identity 
$\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf A)= \nabla^2 \mathbf A +\nabla  \times \nabla \times\mathbf A$  to write

\begin{equation} (\lambda +2\mu) \nabla^2 \mathbf u +(\mu+\lambda)\nabla  \times (\nabla \times\mathbf u) + \mathbf f =0 \end{equation}

So multiplying by a test function $\mathbf v$ I get

\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega \bigg((\lambda +2\mu) \nabla^2 \mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v +(\mu+\lambda)\nabla  \times (\nabla \times\mathbf u)\cdot \mathbf v  + \mathbf f \cdot \mathbf v  \bigg) d\Omega=0 
\end{equation}

and using Green formula, 
\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega \bigg((\lambda +2\mu) (\nabla \mathbf u :\nabla \mathbf v) +(\mu+\lambda)(\nabla  \times \mathbf v)\cdot(\nabla \times\mathbf u) + \mathbf f \cdot \mathbf v  \bigg) d\Omega=0 
\end{equation}
I'm skeptical about this for, since when I compare the bilinear form
\begin{equation}
a(\mathbf u,\mathbf v) := \int_\Omega \bigg((\lambda +2\mu) (\nabla \mathbf u :\nabla \mathbf v) +(\mu+\lambda)(\nabla  \times \mathbf v)\cdot(\nabla \times\mathbf u) \bigg) d\Omega
\end{equation}
With the classical one
\begin{equation}
a(\mathbf u,\mathbf v) := \int_\Omega \sigma(\mathbf u):\varepsilon(\mathbf v) d\Omega
\end{equation}

I got few different terms. For instance, in 2D the "classical" form (noted $a_1$) gives 
\begin{eqnarray}
a_1(\mathbf u,\mathbf v) &=& \int_\Omega \sigma(\mathbf u):\varepsilon(\mathbf v) d\Omega \\&=& \bigg(2\mu \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}+\lambda(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}) \bigg)\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x}
+\mu\bigg(\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x}\bigg)
+\bigg(2\mu \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}+\lambda(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y})\bigg) \frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}
\\&=&(\lambda+2\mu) \bigg(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x} \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}\bigg) 
+ \mu\bigg(\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x}\bigg)
+\lambda\bigg(\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}\bigg)\end{eqnarray}

Whereas, the "rotational" form gives
\begin{eqnarray}
a_2(\mathbf u,\mathbf v) &=& \int_\Omega \bigg((\lambda +2\mu) (\nabla \mathbf u :\nabla \mathbf v) +(\mu+\lambda)(\nabla  \times \mathbf v)\cdot(\nabla \times\mathbf u) \bigg) d\Omega\\
&=& (2\mu+\lambda)\bigg(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} +
\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x} +
\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}\bigg)
+ (\lambda+\mu)\bigg(\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\bigg)
\bigg(\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y} -\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x}\bigg)
\end{eqnarray}
The $(\lambda +\mu)$ terms may be developped and some terms may be factorized with some other terms of $(2\mu+\lambda)$
\begin{eqnarray}
a_2(\mathbf u,\mathbf v) &=& (2\mu+\lambda)\bigg(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x}  +
\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}\bigg)
+\mu\bigg(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x}\bigg)
+ (\lambda+\mu)\bigg(\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x}\bigg)
\end{eqnarray}
The $\mu$ terms in two and second expressions may be factorized 
\begin{eqnarray}
a_2(\mathbf u,\mathbf v) &=& (2\mu+\lambda)\bigg(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}\bigg)
+\mu\bigg(\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x}\bigg)
+ \lambda\bigg(\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x}\bigg)
\end{eqnarray}

This equation is almost the same as $a_1$ except for the $\lambda$ term.
Could someone correct me ?

PS: the rotational being defined by
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \times \mathbf u =
\left|
\begin{array}{l}
\partial_x\\
\partial_y \\
\partial_z
\end{array}
\right.
\times
\left|
\begin{array}{l}
u_x\\
u_y \\
u_z
\end{array}
\right.
=
\left|
\begin{array}{l}
\partial_y u_z -\partial_z u_y\\
\partial_z u_x -\partial_x u_z \\
\partial_x u_y -\partial_y u_x
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
(\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf u ) \cdot \mathbf v =
\left|
\begin{array}{l}
\partial_y (\partial_x u_y -\partial_y u_x) - \partial_z(\partial_z u_x -\partial_x u_z)\\
\partial_z (\partial_y u_z -\partial_z u_y) - \partial_x(\partial_x u_y -\partial_y u_x)\\
\partial_x (\partial_z u_x -\partial_x u_z) - \partial_y (\partial_y u_z -\partial_z u_y)
\end{array}
\right.
\cdot 
\left|
\begin{array}{l}
v_x \\
v_y\\
v_z
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

And using integration by part (but I suspect that the flaw stands here), 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_\Omega (\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf u ) \cdot \mathbf v &=&
-\int_\Omega 
\partial_y v_x(\partial_x u_y -\partial_y u_x) 
- \partial_z v_x (\partial_z u_x -\partial_x u_z)\\
&&+\partial_z  v_y(\partial_y u_z -\partial_z u_y) 
- \partial_x v_y (\partial_x u_y -\partial_y u_x)\\
&&
+\partial_x v_z(\partial_z u_x -\partial_x u_z) 
- \partial_y v_z(\partial_y u_z -\partial_z u_y)\\
&=& - \int_\Omega (\partial_y v_x - \partial_x v_y )(\partial_x u_y -\partial_y u_x) +
(\partial_z  v_y-\partial_y v_z) (\partial_y u_z -\partial_z u_y) 
+(\partial_x v_z- \partial_z v_x )(\partial_z u_x -\partial_x u_z)\\
&=& \int_\Omega (\nabla \times \mathbf v )\cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf u)
\end{eqnarray}

Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be useful to explain what differences you get. What did you try?

Comment: Wolfgang, I have edited the question.

Comment: Although divergence and gradient are defined independent of dimension, this is not the case for the curl. The vector calculus you apply is defined for 3D vector fields. (There is a cross product on 2D vectors, but that is not used here.)

Comment: Also, the last term of your first $a_2$ formula is not symmetric with respect to $u$ and $v$, although the bilinear form obviously is.

Comment: Christian, I did the maths in 3D but with the addtional hypothesis that vector field is zero on the z axis. I know that the form I obtain is not symmetric with respect to derivatives, and this is why is is obviously wrong. But I don't know why.

Comment: Your integration by parts is correct. But there seem to be a few sign errors earlier, e.g., when applying the vector identity, and when going from $a$ to $a_2$ (the last two terms should have flipped sign). I'm also not sure what you mean exactly by the vector field being "zero on the $z$ axis". Why don't you expand all terms in $a_1$ and $a_2$ and compare them one by one?

Comment: Christian, thank you for your comments. I checked the vector identity and no sign error, may be you were confused by the way I used it (generally the rotational term is wiped out, whereas I'm trying to keep it). I'm not sure about the sign flip too, but in any case a sign error would not produce a bilinear form that is not symmetric. I'm almost sure that tehre is some gauge stuff missing here, but maybe I should rephrase the question in: how to use variational method on $\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf u$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Your derivation is correct up to minor imprecisions:
\begin{multline}
\int_\Omega \bigg((\lambda +2\mu) \nabla^2 \mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v +(\mu+\lambda)\nabla  \times (\nabla \times\mathbf u)\cdot \mathbf v  + \mathbf f \cdot \mathbf v  \bigg) d\Omega
= \\ =
-\int_\Omega \bigg((\lambda +2\mu) \nabla \mathbf u :\nabla \mathbf v +(\mu+\lambda)(\nabla  \times \mathbf v)\cdot(\nabla \times\mathbf u) \bigg)d\Omega
+ \\ + 
\int_{\partial \Omega} \bigg((\lambda +2\mu) (\nabla \mathbf u \,\mathbf n) \cdot 
\mathbf v + (\mu+\lambda) \: \mathbf n \times (\nabla \times \mathbf u) \cdot 
\mathbf v \bigg) d \partial \Omega + 
\int_\Omega \big( \mathbf f \cdot \mathbf v  \big) d\Omega
\end{multline}
where $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary and $\mathbf n$ is the unit outward normal.

By inspecting the boundary term it is clear that this is *not* linear elasticity, unless you have Dirichlet b.c. on the whole boundary $\partial \Omega$. The point here is that if you want to recover the proper Neumann b.c. you are not free to integrate by parts at your will: you have to transfer to the test function the *correct* derivatives.