# Equivalence of linear elasticity and biharmonic equations: variational formulation

Tags: elliptic-pde

Wikipedia tells me that the equations for [linear elasticity and biharmonic equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity#The_biharmonic_equation) have the same solution for Dirichlet boundary condition. How do you show the equivalence in the variational formulation?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. Your question is related with [Mathematical Physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_physics), so it might be better to move it to [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics) or even [Mathematics.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics).

Answer (score 3):

The article on Wikipedia does not mention boundary conditions for the biharmonic equation. It is therefore impossible to establish a variational formulation, cfr. this [answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/7863/1744). Please also note that Dirichlet b.c. for the biharmonic equation are written in terms of $u_i$ and $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial n}$ (or some other first order derivative, depending on the problem), while Dirichlet b.c. for linear elasticity are written in terms of $u_i$ alone. It is therefore dubious to claim that

> linear elasticity and biharmonic equations have the same solution for Dirichlet boundary condition

if one does not provides some practical mean for defining a well posed problem for the biharmonic equation equivalent to the elastic problem.

Moreover I had no time to check if the derivation of the biharmonic equation given on Wikipedia is correct (and I do not have access to the classical literature right now) but a lot of *ad hoc* assumptions are made (e.g. $\lambda = -\beta^2$) so I suspect that the supposed *equivalence* is far from being general.