# Is there a difference between the Galerkin MWR and other techniques called Finite Element Method

Tags: finite-element

Recently, I took a course on numerical methods where we learned about Galerkin's Method of Weighted Residuals. We were told that it forms the basis of the Finite Element Method .

However, in most introductory texts I've seen on FEM, they start with a simple example where they manually write out the equations to minimize the potential energy at each node. For instance, see this [example of a system of springs](http://www.msm.cam.ac.uk/phase-trans/mphil/MP7-2.pdf). There are no test functions, so it doesn't seem to be the MWR.

So, my question is:

1. Is there a name for this other method?
2. What are the practical and numerical differences between it and the Galerkin Method of Weighted Residuals? (e.g., is it easier to set up for certain problems? Does it have better numerical precision or stability?)

Comment: The spring (or in higher dimensions, truss) examples are presented first since they are easy to think about, especially for the undergraduate mechanical engineers for whom many of these introductory texts are written. They serve to show the basic workflow of a finite element solution (element tangent --> assembly --> solution) without muddying the water with test functions and other formalities, which can be addressed in detail later. Once you're comfortable with the actual mathematics involved, you can probably safely ignore the physical example system.

Comment: The finite element method is a specific case of Galerkin's method, defined by a special choice of piecewise polynomial functions as test and trial functions. I already gave my opinion on introducing finite element methods via systems of springs or similar in [this answer](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/10681/1804) (contrary to @TylerOlsen, I think this muddies the water rather than the other way around) -- the test functions are there as well, but hidden in the way the systems are assembled in a purely local fashion.

Comment: @ChristianClason Just read the other answer, and that's fair enough, but you'd have to be in a math class for that approach. I had it introduced to me in a structural mechanics class, so the audience was right for the mechanical interpretation, I suppose.

Comment: 1.  I often hear "this other method" referred to as the direct stiffness method.  2.  Weighted residuals exploits the strong form of the PDE, while FEM exploits the weak form of the PDE.  See [this answer](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7845/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-integration-by-parts-in-deriving-a-weak-form-for-fe) for more details.

Comment: You can derive the equations for those spring systems minimizing the Lagrangian of the system. In that sense it can be closer to what you see in FEM.

Comment: I think your question already has an answer here: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7845/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-integration-by-parts-in-deriving-a-weak-form-for-fe

Comment: @ChristianClason Thanks for the link to your other answer. So what you are saying is that these introductory examples do have test functions, but based on the choice of test functions, it boils down to a very simple expression?

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the reference to the direct stiffness method.

Comment: @nnn Almost -- the fact that each node only couples to neighboring nodes implies a specific choice of test and ansatz functions (which are indeed very simple in this concrete introductory example).